# Redirect URL using phonegap

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, cordova, twitter, instagram

I'm building a phonegap app in which I need to link to facebook, instagram and twitter. I need to allow users to login to each of these with their credentials and return an access token which I will be saving on the device using local storage. I can login the users perfectly fine when working on an actual site (which is a test site I have setup). The way it works is I have to redirect the user to a login page for each brand where they can login. This I can do fine from a phonegap app, but the issue is that each of them require a redirect url which I must supply for them to basically send the access token to once the user logs in. On the internet this works perfect, but I need to redirect url to somehow point back to the mobile device it originated from. I can do this using a proxy but I don't want to employ the use of a server as this comes with way to much overhead. So all that to actually ask my question:

How the heck do I redirect the user back to the mobile app after they have successfully logged in? I'm hoping this is something very simple that I'm missing, but I'm just not seeing it. :/

Comment: Hi, I guess u might have solved this problem. If so, please explain how did you solve it? Please help, thanks.

Comment: @ErmaIsabel i ended up using phonegap's built in inapp browser. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser. i open up the browser and direct them to the appropriate login screen. once logged in they are redirected to my website. i then use phonegap to capture the url (which includes the token) then simply close the inapp browser. hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is oAuth authentication which logs the user in and then tells the user's browser to go to the second URL.  Typically, if you write an iOS app, you can always open it by doing something like this: ://.  it should also be able to ready parameters passed this way.

For example: open safari on your iPhone and put "Skype://" as the address and it should open your skype app if you have it installed.

Try setting the return URL similar to what I mention above and see if that works.